# I want my discord to send in a chosen discord text channel

Tags: python, discord

I want my discord bot to send a message in a set channel. right now it sends in the first channel it have access to.

```
here is the code

import discord
from discord import app_commands
from config import *

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await tree.sync()
    print("Online!")

@tree.command(
    name="nensi",
    description="Send a global message!",
)
@app_commands.describe(text = "Do not leak any personal information")
async def nensi(interaction: discord.Interaction, text: str):
    for server in client.guilds:
        for channel in server.text_channels:
            try:
                await channel.send(f"{interaction.user.mention} said: {text}")
            except Exception:
                continue
            else:
                break

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I want to make a file by it self where i can put in discord channel IDs and have it message inside them.

Ive tried everything inside my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

So currently, when someone invokes the `nensi` command you're looping through all the servers your bot is in, then looping through all the channels, but as soon as you successfully send a message you exit (that's what the `else: break` statement is doing). If you want to send a message to a specific channel - why not just use the ID of that channel?

```py
# define somewhere your channel variable
YOUR_CHANNEL_ID = 1234123123123

@app_commands.describe(text="Do not leak any personal information")
async def nensi(interaction: discord.Interaction, text: str):
    channel = await client.fetch_channel(YOUR_CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send(f"{interaction.user.mention} said: {text}")
    
    # respond to the interaction ephemerally so the user knows the command did something
    # also prevents slash command creating an error in discord client
    await interaction.response.send(content="Done", ephemeral=True)
```

To get IDs of channels, guilds, users, etc you have to turn on `Developer Mode`. This is easy to do:

- -> User Settings
- -> App Settings just a category - not a menu)
- -> Advanced
- -> Toggle Developer Mode

Then if you right-click the specific channel you want to send the message too, you will be able to copy the ID of that channel.